# Is it safe to modify shared_ptr in an (unordered_)set?

Tags: c++, stl, set, shared-ptr, unordered-set

Elements stored in a `set` or `unordered_set` are immutable. If one changes an element that is stored in a `set` this may lead to the set not working properly anymore.
However, does this include the pointed-to object when storing `shared_ptr` in a set?

As far as `set` is concerned it uses `less()` to compare two objects. The result should not change if the pointed to object changes or if the ref count changes. So I would understand that it is totally safe to have a set of `shared_ptr` and modify the pointed-to objects.

However, since `unordered_set` uses `hash()` to calculate the hash of its elements, which is equivalent to calling `hash()` on the pointed-to object of a `shared_ptr`, modifying the pointed-to object would get us into trouble.

Is this correct?

Comment: AFAIK, both hash and operators work on the pointer rather than the pointee... So modifying the pointee should have no effect, IMO seems meaning less to store in a set or map, a vector I would have though would also suffice..

Comment: That's right Nim - per [ccppreference re hash](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/hash) "std::hash<std::shared_ptr<T>>()(p) == std::hash<T*>()(p.get())" - so only the pointer is hashed, and [shared_ptr `<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp) "simply compare pointer values; the actual objects pointed to are not compared."

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake when checking the implementation of hash<shared_ptr<T>>. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: ... unless you specialize the operator or the hash function, respectively.

Comment: I think this question smells of a bad decision for a container of shared ptrs.

Comment: @user1095108 Why do you think that? It totally depends on the use case. I find a set of shared pointers convenient if the order doesn't matter. (However, `unordered_set` makes much more sense than `set`)

Comment: @user1095108 Can you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hash()` for a smart pointer is equivalent to `hash()` for the pointer value, but `hash()` for the pointer value depends only on the pointer, not on the pointee. So you are safe to modify objects in the container - hash function results will not be changed.

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake when checking the implementation of hash<shared_ptr<T>>. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

The hash function for `shared_ptr<T>` does not rely on the state of the instance to which it points. So you can safely modify the state without invalidating the container.

Comment: Thanks Rex, I didn't know about the ''s.

Comment: If you use `std::less<shared_ptr<T>>` for what? The comparison function? Unordered set does not use a relational comparison, it uses a hash function. And in the case of collisions, an equality comparison, a role which `std::less<shared_ptr<T>>` could not fulfill.

Comment: Use the [grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) to surround inline code, not the single quote. Top left corner, below ESC, unshifted, at least on the keyboards I'm used to seeing.

Answer (score -1):

STL set uses red-black tree as implementation - (the reason for this is to have uniform  insert time; no linear worst cases like in hash map); if you change the key then the tree is no longer balanced; the implementation uses operator< and operator== , not the hash.

unordered set uses the bucket hashtable as implementation; here the hash is used; changing the key would mean that the entry would no longer belong to the same bucket of the hash table.

shared_ptr's operator< and operator== compares the pointer value that is held by the smart pointer, still changing the key will not maintain the ordering relationship of the data structure that implements this 'container'.

hash value will of shared ptr will be just the numeric value of the wrapped pointer

```
  template<typename _Tp, _Lock_policy _Lp>
    struct hash<__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>>
    : public std::unary_function<__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>, size_t>
    {
      size_t
      operator()(const __shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>& __s) const
      { return std::hash<_Tp*>()(__s.get()); }
    };

template<typename _Tp>
  struct hash<_Tp*> : public __hash_base<size_t, _Tp*>
  {
    size_t
    operator()(_Tp* __p) const
    { return reinterpret_cast<size_t>(__p); }
  };
```

On gcc stl:

```
c++/<version>/map inculudes c++/<version>/bits/stl_set.h 

c++/<version>/bits/stl_set.h

  template<typename _Key, typename _Compare = std::less<_Key>,
           typename _Alloc = std::allocator<_Key> >
    class set
    {
   typedef _Rb_tree<key_type, value_type, _Identity<value_type>,
                    key_compare, _Key_alloc_type> _Rep_type;
   _Rep_type _M_t;  // Red-black tree representing set.

c++/<version>/bits/tree.h
    <here red black tre _Rb_tree class is implemented>

 c++/<version>/unordered_set includs c++/<version>/bits/unordered_set.h this one uses hashtable in c++/<version>/bits/hashtable.h
```

Comment: "[`set`] uses operator< and operator==" - just `<` actually, it infers equality when neither `a < b` nor `b < a`.  More generally, I think the question is about whether changing the pointed-to data constitutes a change to the key for the purposes of `set`'s `<` and `unordered_set`'s `hash`....

Comment: Thanks, but this was more or less already stated in my question ;)

Comment: shared_ptr's operator< and operator== compares the pointer value that is held by the smart pointer, still changing the key will not maintain the ordering relationship of the data structure that implements this 'container'.